# HTML Form using php doesn't update mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

when I change information in the form, that information should be put in $_POST. Next, the  `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))` should run the query to update the table in MySQL. However, nothing gets updated in the MySQL. I'm assuming that there is a simple fix because I'm learning this.

Also, any advice about how to debug something like this would be helpful. I'm using notepad++ and the school's server.

```
<?php require_once("session.php"); ?>
<?php 
  require_once("included_functions.php");
  new_header("Here is Who's who!", "CRUD/editPeople.php"); 
  $mysqli = db_connection();
  if (($output = message()) !== null) {
     echo $output;
  }

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $ID = $_GET["id"];
     // UPDATE query on $ID
     $query = "UPDATE people SET ";
     $query .= "FirstName = '".$_POST["FirstName"];
     $query .= "', LastName = '".$_POST["LastName"];
     $query .= "', Birthdate = '".$_POST["Birthdate"];
     $query .= "', BirthCity = '".$_POST["BirthCity"];
     $query .= "', BirthState = '".$_POST["BirthState"];
     $query .= "', Region = '".$_POST["Region"]."' ";
     $query .= "WHERE PersonID = {$ID}";
     //Output query results and return to readPeople.php
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);

     if($result) {
       $_SESSION["message"] = $_POST["FirstName"]." ".$_POST["LastName"]." has been changed";
     } else {
       $_SESSION["message"] = "Error! Could not change ".$_POST["FirstName"]." ".$_POST["LastName"];
     }
     //Once the Edit has been completed (CHANGE button clicked)
     //redirect to the readPeople.php webpage
     header("Location: readPeople.php");
     exit;
   } else { 
  // GET id and create a query to SELECT * on the id
      if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] !== "") {
      // Get id
      $ID = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['id']));

      $query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE ";
      $query .= "PersonID = '".$ID."'";
      $result = $mysqli->query($query);
      //Process query
      if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
         $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "<div class='row'>";
         echo "<label for='left-label' class='left inline'>";
         echo "<h3>".$row["FirstName"]." ".$row["LastName"]."'s Profile</h3>";

         // Create form with inputs for each field in people table
         echo "<p><form action = 'editPeople.php?id={$ID}' method='post'>";
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'FirstName' value = '".
             $row["FirstName"]."'/></p>";
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'LastName' value = '".
             $row["LastName"]."'/></p>";
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'Birthdate' value = '".
             $row["Birthdate"]."'/></p>"; 
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'BirthCity' value = '".
             $row["BirthCity"]."'/></p>";
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'BirthState' value = '".
             $row["BirthState"]."' /></p>";
         echo "<p><input type = 'text' name = 'Region' value = '".
             $row["Region"]."' /></p>";

         echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Update' /></p>";  
         echo "</form>";
    echo "<br /><p>&laquo:<a href='readPeople.php'>Back to Main Page</a>";
    echo "</label>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
         //Query failed to exit. Return to readPeople.php and output error
         else {
         $_SESSION["message"] = "Person could not be found!";
         header("Location: readPeople.php");
         exit;
    }}}
?>
<?php  new_footer("Who's Who"); ?>
```

Comment: You must give name to your submit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML form, there is no any input with `name="submit"` so `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))` this condition is false.

Add `name="submit"` in your submit button

```
echo "<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' /></p>";
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To debug and to find what is passing through I use `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_GET)`.

I use this in most scripts that uses forms, to have control over what is passing along. But of course only on development server.

Answer (score 0):

Your button don't have a name. Put name="submit" in button. Because of this the isset($_POST['SUBMIT']) is not working.